# CRM Dynamics and record access

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

In CRM Dynamics I have a business owner team called Team X, and the team contains 2 members:

- Member A
- Member B

If I assign record to Team X then the record is visible to both user, this is correct. However if the record is assigned to Member A then the record is no longer visible to Member B and vice versa. Is there any way to make the record still visible to Member B if owned by Member A and visible to Member A if owned by Member B?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an automation that will handle the update of owner field and perform sharing of the record with Team X.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other option but without the need to share record?

Comment: There might be other ways but I'm not aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new User Role and make the read permission for a business unit

then assigned this role to the users

Comment: Thanks, but I only want Team X to be able to access records owned by Team or records owned by a any member of that Team X

Comment: you can add each team to BU to separate each team records

Answer (score 0):

*Update the **security role** for Team X, set the **read by BU** and **write/update by user**

*or create workflow on create **set owner to Team X**